# Calendar Sharing

Tags: exchange-2010, calendar

We have an office where people share read/write access to their calendars with each other.  We are on Exchange 2010 and they are all using Outlook 2010.

While most people are doing this without a problem, there is one case that when person A attempts to grant person B calendar permissions, he is met with the error message:

> One or more users cannot be added to the folder access list.  Non-local users cannot be given rights on this server.

This is strange because both users are in the same domain and B has no trouble granting permissions to A.

I created an outlook profile on another computer and granted myself full access permissions to A's mailbox (*with A's blessing*) to replicate the problem.  When I load their mailbox with my credentials on a new machine, I see the same problem.  For some reason, when A views the GAL, it appears that B is a non-local user.  Deleting and downloading a new OAB hasn't helped.

B appears local to everyone else.

What can cause this?  What troubleshooting steps can I take to resolve it?  Is there a setting in A's account that can cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.

About a dozen of our users had mailboxes of type SharedMailbox.  Not sure how that happened or why it only affected one person but converting back to a regular UserMailbox resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

When this error seems to be completely erroneous, and you can't find a rational explanation,  it's usually, (in my experience) that the user (Mr. `A`, in your case) has a misconfigured attribute in AD, `msExchRecipientDisplayType`.  Use ADSIedit to clear the value stored in the attribute and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thanks.  Tried it but didn't do it.

Comment: @bob At least you figured it out.  Be sure to accept your answer so this question doesn't stay in the unanswered list forever.